# Snowshoeing/hiking in December in Geneva

Tags: hiking, camping, geneva

I'm looking for locations for snowshoeing or hiking that can be done at the end of December in Switzerland, preferably in the proximity of Geneva (1-2 hours away is okay). If the treks involve one night of camping, that would even be better :). Can anyone help with some info?

Comment: pnuts suggestion is great.  You basically have an enormous number of choices.  it would be like asking where to buy a hotdog in NYC you know?  Note that the local ski areas for Geneve are places like ..................... Mont Blanc.  :)  And Chamonix.  :)  So you won't have any problems.  FYI if you've not been to CG/Europe before, note that Zurich is more sort of "in the mountains" (perhaps you could change your stopover/whatever to there).  Genève is like "just on the end" of the mountains.  (Don't get me wrong - plenty of mountains!) You're just at the flat plains of France, in Genève.

Comment: In general, consider really to choose **Chamonix** in general .............. "the cathedral of mountains".  It's mindboggling.

Comment: if you state how many nites you are staying in Genève it will help people give advice

Comment: For a not-insignificant additional cost but completely doable under the 2-hour limit, you can cross the Mont-Blanc tunnel, the view from Courmayeur is also breathtaking and I assume you can find interesting hiking there too (although December does not seem like the best season for this: snow cover isn't guaranteed in most places and adverse weather is a serious possibility if you go too high, you should not spend the night in the mountains unprepared).

Comment: Indeed, you can ***drive to Italy***, for goodness sake, from Genève!!  Go to Aosta!!! This question is like shooting fish in a barrel eh?  :)   Handy tip: there are infuriating speed cameras on the last little bit where you drive up the hill (1-2 miles) to the tunnel entrance on the French side.

Answer (score 1):

Just one man's suggestion - if you like Skyscrapers, you have to see Bombay and New York once in your life.  If you like food and clothes, you have to go to Italy. If you surf, Hawaii. And so on.

If you like mountains, you pretty much have to go to Chamonix in general, once in your life.  The "cathedral of mountains".  When you stand there on the right day and look around (ie: up) it's mindboggling, like it's not real.

There is of course any amount of snowshoeing in Chamonix http://www.chamonix.net/english/winter-activities/snowshoeing (google 'Chamonix snowshoeing' for endless resources).

Train from Genève -> Chamonix is a bit of a mess (of course, any train travel is nice/fun) and takes 3+hrs.  You can take a bus in 1+ hrs.  I would trul urge you to **simply rent a car**.  Everything in Switzerland is insanely expensive, and it's no great cost to rent a car, and you have huge benefits: scenery, get to exactly where you want, huge time saving etc.  Note that depending on your trip, just rent a car at the airport. Forget about Genève per se and just drive to your mountains. If you like, take 15 minutes extra to just drive around Genève so you have seen it. Enjoy!

---

Just to repeat, "snow near Genève?" is a bit like "Hotdogs in NY?" heh. Merely one bucket-list possibility, take the once-in-a-lifetime train from Genève to **Zermatt**, for goodness sake. That would be incredible.  Enjoy!

Comment: (+1) Note that starting from Geneva, nearly the entirety of the trip is in France (which might be why the train is not very convenient… but it should be cheaper than in Switzerland!) You need to cross Geneva one way or the other to go to Chamonix (although you won't see much if you take the motorway to Bardonnex of course).

Comment: right on - sure, you'd just turn left and drive over to the downtown area (OP: Genève is only the size of a large village! it's great), you'd look at the lake, you'd look at Cote d'Entrecote, you'd look at a watch shop, and be on your way. If you want you could park the car (easy) and walk around the central mall area for two minutes. I guess your GPS would just take you out through the shitty suburbs (Thonex is it? - that side), join the road to Mont Blanc / Chamonix / Italie.  Enjoy!